# .getBytes() in Swift 1.2 gives trouble

Tags: xcode6, swift

In Swift 1.2, I am trying to compile the md5 implementation that I found on [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/MD5/Implementation#Swift).
One single line gives me an error and I cannot figure out why.

This is the line:

```
chunk.getBytes(M[x], range:range)
```

This is the error I get:

> Cannot invoke 'getBytes' with an argument of type'(UInt32, range: _NSRange)'

And this is the context:

```
// break chunk into sixteen 32-bit words M[j], 0 ≤ j ≤ 15
let wordSize = sizeof(UInt32)
var M:[UInt32] = [UInt32](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
for x in 0..<M.count {
    var range = NSRange(location:x * wordSize, length: wordSize)
    chunk.getBytes(M[x], range:range)
}
```

(BTW, the same line worked well in the previous version of Swift)

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: It looks like they've updated the code for Swift 1.2 at the original site: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that works in Swift 1.1 is (note the `&` operator):

```
chunk.getBytes(&M[x], range:range)
```

but this does indeed not compile anymore with Swift 1.2. 
You can replace the line with the equivalent code

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&M[x]) { chunk.getBytes($0, range:range) }
```

or use a temporary variable

```
var tmp = UInt32(0)
chunk.getBytes(&tmp, range:range)
M[x] = tmp
```

to make it work again.

But note that the loop is actually not needed at all, and your
code can be simplified to

```
let wordSize = sizeof(UInt32)
var M = [UInt32](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
chunk.getBytes(&M, length: M.count * wordSize)
```

which compiles with Swift 1.1 and 1.2.